# How to parse FQL response of Facebook pages by category and/or location? (Python)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Long time listener, first time caller..

I'm getting a good result from my Facebook Open Graph API query:

```
fbtest = graph.request("/fql", {"q": "SELECT name, page_id, categories, location 
FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me())"})
```

And although I've taken Zed's great course on [Learning Python the Hard Way](http://www.udemy.com/learn-python-the-hard-way/), I'm still green and need help on these fronts:

1. I'd love to ONLY request pages that match certain categories, such as "Local Business" but because 'categories' is a list (and it's not indexed in the FB table), I'm having a tough time figuring it out; I'm assuming it's not possible.
2. So I retrieve the full blast of ALL pages that a person likes, and I need to sort it out afterwards. Here's what I'm having trouble doing:

How do I manipulate the results (filtering by category and/or location, which are both lists) and send them in a readable format to my fbtest.html file?

Currently I am just rendering the output of fbtest in HTML;

```
self.render("test.html", fbtest=fbtest)
```

which is pretty ugly:

> fbtest: {u'data': [{u'page_id': 8495417058L, u'name': u'Mat Zo',
>   u'categories': [], u'location': {u'street': u'', u'zip': u''}},
>   {u'page_id': 9980651805L, u'name': u'deadmau5', u'categories': [],
>   u'location': {u'street': u'', u'zip': u''}}, {u'page_id': 6209079710L,
>   u'name': u'Ultra Records', u'categories': [], u'location': {u'street':
>   u'', u'zip': u''}}, {u'page_id': 12609724042L, u'name': u'Oceanlab',
>   u'categories': [], u'location': {u'street': u'', u'zip': u''}}, etc

And as soon as I try to manipulate the list, I can send a single result (like the page matching name = "thesocialbusiness") but not a series of results that I'm looking for. My vision is to have a nice picture-book thumbnail view of pages that is categorized and sorted by location.

Thanks and happy holidays,

-James

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're just looking to filter the end result here? If you haven't already, go ahead and convert the json string to a python object

```
import json
resp = json.loads(fql_resp)
data = resp['data']
```

The `loads` stands for *load string* which is what you'll be getting back from the service. From here you have a few options. One choice is to use the builtin `filter` if you know before hand what categories you want. Take for example the following data set

```
objs = [{'_id': 1, 'categories': ['a', 'b', 'c']},
        {'_id': 2, 'categories': ['b']},
        {'_id': 3, 'categories': ['c']}]
```

You could filter results that only contain the `b` category like so

```
def f(obj):
    return 'b' in obj['categories']

filtered_objs = filter(f, objs)
print(filtered_objs)
# outputs:
# [{'_id': 1, 'categories': ['a', 'b', 'c']},
#  {'_id': 2, 'categories': ['b']}]
```

if you want a reusable function to filter for different categories you could do something like

```
def filter_objs(objs, category):
    result = []
    for obj in objs:
        if category in obj['categories']:
            result.append(category)
    return result

filtered_objs = filter_objs(objs, 'b')
```

And lastly, you could just use a list comprehension, either inline as needed or in the filter_objs function.

```
filtered_objs = [obj for obj in objs if 'b' in obj['categories']]
```

So there's a number of ways to filter the result, but the first step is to use `json.loads`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help and the different options, especially the reusable function. I'm thinking I will go with that.

Comment: It looks like there's something funky going on with the initial load function - I get this error from the json.load line:    fbtest2 = json.loads(fbtest)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: what do you get if you print type(fbtest)

Comment: I get <type 'dict'>   Also I tried just jumping into the filtering process and was able to get an empty result set. I'm wondering if the 'categories' value is a bit more complicated, because when I look at the fbtest data, here's an example: u'name': u'The Blacksmith Restaurant', u'categories': [{u'id': 0, u'name': u'Restaurant/Cafe'}] - so maybe i have to use some sort of 'categories':'name' filter? Thanks for your help @dskinner

Comment: okay so its already a python object, the fbtest you have printed above is a json object which translates to a python dict, so your list of results are in fbtest['data'], and if categories is a list of objects, then you'll want to loop through them and match against needed property, such as `for c in obj['categories']: if category == c['name']: result.append(obj); break`

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep working on it. I'm unsure of whether you're using 'obj' as a generic variable or a Python 'object'. When I use this `code def filter_objs(obj, category):
            result = []
            for c in obj['categories']:
                if category == c['name']:
                    result.append(obj); break
           
        fbtest4 = filter_objs(fbtest['data'], 'Company')` I get "global name 'obj' is not defined", and if I change the first line from 'objs' to 'obj' I get for c in obj['categories']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str  =)